# compiling lua applications using wxluafreeze problems

Tags: compilation, lua, wxwidgets, wxlua

I am having a problem trying to compile a lua script to exe with wxluafreeze. I am typing this  into cmd (all the files are in the same directory)-

```
wxluafreeze.lua "wxluafreeze.exe" "test.lua" "newprog.exe"
```

as well as

```
wxluafreeze.lua wxluafreeze.exe test.lua newprog.exe
```

but it keeps spitting out the text that tells you how to use wxluafreeze (ie, the text that appears when you input no arguments). I have never compiled a lua script to an executable before, so I am kind of lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of lua are you using?

Comment: lua 5.1, latest version of wxLua

Answer (score 0):

For example in MSW in the wxLua\bin dir(you need copy "wxluafreeze.lua" to this dir for convenience):
lua.exe wxluafreeze.lua wxluafreeze.exe myprogram.wx.lua myprogram.exe

Comment: the spelling should adjust to the local file name, eg: the "wxluafreeze.exe" is  "wxLuaFreeze.exe" in my disk. what else, when I process this cmd,  it pops up an error that the open files mode is invalid in line 87 of wxluafreeze.lua. Then I removed the operator "+" and processed it again, the exe  file came out. hope this may help you

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38493053/edit) your answer instead of adding a comment.